# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, dictionary

I am trying to parse Google Map Web Service JSON, here is my code. Data is an array parsed from JSON

```
- (void)plotPositions:(NSMutableArray *)data
{
    //Loop through the array of places returned from the Google API.
    for (int i=0; i<[data count]; i++)
    {
    //Retrieve the NSDictionary object in each index of the array.
    NSDictionary *place = [data objectAtIndex:i];

    //retrieve photo preference number
    NSDictionary *photo = [place objectForKey:@"photos"];
    NSLog(@"photo %@", photo);

    //There is a specific NSDictionary object that gives us location info.
    NSDictionary *geo = [place objectForKey:@"geometry"];

    //Get our name and address info for adding to a pin.
    NSString *name=[place objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *vicinity=[place objectForKey:@"vicinity"];
    NSLog(name, vicinity);
    [displayName addObject:name];
    [searchLocation addObject:vicinity];
    [ThumbnilURL addObject:[place objectForKey:@"icon"]];

    //Get the lat and long for the location.
    NSDictionary *loc = [geo objectForKey:@"location"];

    //Create a special variable to hold this coordinate info.
    CLLocationCoordinate2D placeCoord;

    //Set the lat and long.
    placeCoord.latitude=[[loc objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
    placeCoord.longitude=[[loc objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];

    //get photo preference
    NSLog(@"photo reference %@", [photo objectForKey:@"photo_reference"]);

    }
}
```

Whenever I try to parse the photo dictionary to get "photo_reference", xcode gives an error. Here is the photo dictionary:

```
(
    {
    height = 4896;
    "html_attributions" =         (
        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114143467670122734398/photos\">Tim Stewart</a>"
    );
    "photo_reference" = "CmRdAAAAiXB3cFbK3GXj0_SJz6x6K01vccCo5Vu7kVBLDIATT6YaPwzfThX7TnmLeTZHL-QYpQYF3MH1aw-3vVoc58-d3FfWUexbLqf6ioScZfAbU9XUh2A7HX-A1BFoZ1hetbcFEhCPVmWQfCFXWPuTkV6Qya6eGhTQ-sn_mkWO8IV3-_2PnD4GTH7w9A";
    width = 3672;
    }
)
```

Can someone please tell me what's my problem. NOTE: the photo dictionary is part of a larger dictionary which contains "vicinity", "icon", "lat", "lng"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are being given an array (NSArray) but you are trying to type it and treat it as a dictionary (NSDictionary). What you are calling a "photo dictionary" is *not*, in fact, a dictionary. It is, as your own `NSLog(@"photo %@", photo)` result shows you, an array (containing, in this case, one *element* which *is* a dictionary).